# Google Docs link preview functionality displays incorrect thumbnail Image

Tags: google-docs

The link details that popups by mousing over a hyperlink in Google docs shows a preview of the link with a thumbnail image and short description.

Recently, found a webpage from our website in Google docs displays irrelevant thumbnail image in the link preview instead of the website logo.

Is there any information on how a website can ensure the image in the link preview that Google docs pulls  deliver the correct preview image?